# Dropwizard Freemarker Configuration: FreemarkerViewRenderer, ViewRenderer and ServiceFinder(jersey)

Tags: templates, jersey, freemarker, dropwizard

I'm trying to use freemarker templates for String entities, but I dont know how to get and process the templates.

In this post -> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/BUcI9y2FjLs the first post says, that "it seems that the only way to access the Freemarker configuration object would be to implement my own version of FreemarkerViewRenderer".

Can anyone confirm that or is there another way to create custom messages from freemarker templates?

Does anyone knows how to implement my own version of FreemarkerViewRenderer and add it to Dropwizard, so that it is accesible in my ressource classes?

As far as I know I can get the FreemarkerViewRenderer with this:

```
        Iterable<ViewRenderer> found = com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.find(ViewRenderer.class);
        for (ViewRenderer vr : found) {
            System.out.println(vr.getClass().getName());        
        }
```

But how can I overwrite this class with additional getConfig()?

Comment: It should be possible to create new freemarker config, but I have no idea, what side effects will occur. Does anyone knows if it is a bad idea to have two freemarker configs? One build oneself and one by Dropwizard? Or is this just a singelton in the end? All I found out is, that in every tutorial it is said, re-use the configuration object and do not create twice or one if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that the configuration class can be manually build (see freemarker+java tutorials). Then you have DW  freemarker instance and your own. That should be no problem. The main problem with creating a new freemarker config is, that it is not very cheap, what means, building a config for every request is a bad idea, but if you have only 2 config instances, then there should be no problem.

In the end, I created my own config and DW has a second config. The config cache will be lost, if you create a new one, but I build just one config instance to serve all my requests, so losing cache information is no problem for me.